# Unity Split Stereo Display

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, stereoscopy

Turning on "Split Stereo Display (non head-mounted)" results in the scene being rendered side by side. It is worth noting that the objects appear without any distortion, the proportions are as-is.

[image]

The ASUS VG268HR monitor features a "3D Side-by-Side (Half)" mode, which alternately displays the left and the right half at full resolution and which may be used together with, for example, Nvidia 3D glasses. Obviously, stretching the above halves to full monitor width changes the proportions of the cube, see below.

[image]

What is the best way to address this problem in Unity? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you,

Bernhard

Comment: Would you mind sharing any relevant scripts in case the problem has something to do with the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try using two separate cameras, and using a RenderTexture on each camera, set each one to the actual proper aspect ratio, then inside the canvas squeeze it so it only fills half the display horizontally. When the issue occurs, it should undo the effect you just made making it look normal again.

Assuming this happens on only certain configurations, I'd suggest making sure there's a way to enable/disable this in the game's settings. You're welcome.